# Select subgroup of shapes in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I'm trying to get a group of shapes within a group of shapes. Like in the following example:

```
sub test()
    Dim shape1      AS Shape
    Dim shape2      AS Shape
    Dim shape3      AS Shape
    Dim shape4      AS Shape
    Dim subGroup1   AS Shape
    Dim subGroup2   AS Shape
    Dim masterGroup AS Shape

    set shape1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle,0,0,100,10)
    shape1.name = "name1"
    set shape2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle,0,0,100,10)
    shape2.name = "name2"
    set subGroup1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("name1", "name2")).Group
    subGroup1.name = "subName1"

    set shape3 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle,0,0,100,10)
    shape3.name = "name3"
    set shape4 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle,0,0,100,10)
    shape4.name = "name4"
    set subGroup2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("name3", "name4")).Group
    subGroup2.name = "subName2"

    set masterGroup = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("subName1", "subName2")).Group
    masterGroup.name = "masterGroup"

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("subName1")).Select
End Sub
```

But later in code I want to be able to select just the **subGroup1** or **subGroup2**.
I'm able to use

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("masterGroup"))
or
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("name1")) 'or any other single shape name
```

But if I select a "subNamex" it throws me an error like this group don't exists.

The weird part is that, if I ungroup the masterGroup it shows the **subGroup1** and **subGroup2** on *ActiveSheet.Shapes*

If Excel can show me the subgroups when I ungroup the master one, where it saves the subgroups and how can I retrieve them?

Comment: I've submitted a Feedback regarding this issue to Microsoft: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/d2b24e87-08b2-ed11-a81b-002248519701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Looks like a bug

This problem doesn't seem to be limited to VBA or even to Excel (see this [PowerPoint related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809460/access-shape-group-within-a-group-in-vba) for instance).

Even if you try to create a subgroup of shapes manually with the Excel interface, you won't be able to select the subgroup by itself. When you try to select a subgroup, it will just select the last range that you had selected:

[image: Animated GIF showing the manipulations in Excel]

Hence, it seems like it's a bug within Excel (and other Office Applications), so you won't be able to use the `Range` method of the `Shapes` object to access all the shapes in the subgroup.

---

#### But where is the information stored?

As you may know, Excel files are just a zip file in disguise. So, if you save your file and make a copy of it, you can change the extension from .xlsm to .zip and look at the XML files that make up the Excel file.

And if you go to `FileName.zip > xl > drawings`, you'll find an XML file that corresponds to the Activesheet with that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xdr:wsDr xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing"
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
    <xdr:twoCellAnchor>
        <xdr:from>
            <xdr:col>0</xdr:col>
            <xdr:colOff>609599</xdr:colOff>
            <xdr:row>2</xdr:row>
            <xdr:rowOff>0</xdr:rowOff>
        </xdr:from>
        <xdr:to>
            <xdr:col>4</xdr:col>
            <xdr:colOff>0</xdr:colOff>
            <xdr:row>8</xdr:row>
            <xdr:rowOff>190497</xdr:rowOff>
        </xdr:to>
        <xdr:grpSp>
            <xdr:nvGrpSpPr>
                <xdr:cNvPr id="8" name="MasterGroup">
                    <a:extLst>
                        <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                            <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{D1B8F46E-61EC-72E1-4A14-5286A67228EA}"/>
                        </a:ext>
                    </a:extLst>
                </xdr:cNvPr>
                <xdr:cNvGrpSpPr/>
            </xdr:nvGrpSpPr>
            <xdr:grpSpPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="609599" y="381000"/>
                    <a:ext cx="1828801" cy="1333497"/>
                    <a:chOff x="609599" y="381000"/>
                    <a:chExt cx="1828801" cy="1333497"/>
                </a:xfrm>
            </xdr:grpSpPr>
            <xdr:grpSp>
                <xdr:nvGrpSpPr>
                    <xdr:cNvPr id="4" name="subName1">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{35F6BC37-8094-8CF0-63DF-07CD98FF746E}"/>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </xdr:cNvPr>
                    <xdr:cNvGrpSpPr/>
                </xdr:nvGrpSpPr>
                <xdr:grpSpPr>
                    <a:xfrm>
                        <a:off x="609600" y="381000"/>
                        <a:ext cx="1828800" cy="381000"/>
                        <a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
                        <a:chExt cx="1270000" cy="127000"/>
                    </a:xfrm>
                </xdr:grpSpPr>
                <xdr:sp macro="" textlink="">
                    <xdr:nvSpPr>
                        <xdr:cNvPr id="2" name="name1">
                            <a:extLst>
                                <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                    <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{038A975F-38AE-0FF4-58A0-A11CAF14EA4F}"/>
                                </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                        </xdr:cNvPr>
                        <xdr:cNvSpPr/>
                    </xdr:nvSpPr>
                    <xdr:spPr>
                        <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="846667" y="0"/>
                            <a:ext cx="423333" cy="127000"/>
                        </a:xfrm>
                        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                            <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstGeom>
                    </xdr:spPr>
                    <xdr:style>
                        <a:lnRef idx="2">
                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
                                <a:shade val="50000"/>
                            </a:schemeClr>
                        </a:lnRef>
                        <a:fillRef idx="1">
                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                        </a:fillRef>
                        <a:effectRef idx="0">
                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                        </a:effectRef>
                        <a:fontRef idx="minor">
                            <a:schemeClr val="lt1"/>
                        </a:fontRef>
                    </xdr:style>
                    <xdr:txBody>
                        <a:bodyPr vertOverflow="clip" horzOverflow="clip" rtlCol="0" anchor="t"/>
                        <a:lstStyle/>
                        <a:p>
                            <a:pPr algn="l"/>
                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-CA" sz="1100"/>
                        </a:p>
                    </xdr:txBody>
                </xdr:sp>
                [...]
```

So, I guess that would be where you can find where the data is stored when the Excel file is saved. There is no easy way to get that information in real-time from the Excel application unfortunatly.

---

#### A workaround?

If you wanted to be fancy, you could write a macro that retrieves the XML data above and parses it to recover the shapes that are part of a specific subgroup, but that might be a little overkill.

Instead, I would suggest to just prepend the name of the subgroup to your shape names, so you can loop through your shapes and recover the ones with a name that starts with the subgroup name.